# How do I implement an escrow service using Bitcoin contracts?

Tags: escrow, contracts

I can see that Bitocin can provide escrow contracts. https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Contracts#Example_2:_Escrow_and_dispute_mediation

Can someone provide a worked example or even better a pointer to a code example.

Answer (score 7):

The functionality is not yet implemented in Bitcoin. On October 18 Gavin created 3 Bitcoin Improvement Proposals that would support the functionality, [Bitcointalk:OP_EVAL proposal](https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=46538.msg583615#msg583615).

- [M-of-N Standard Transactions](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/BIP_0011)
- [OP_EVAL](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/BIP_0012)
- [Address Format for OP_EVAL](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/BIP_0013)